When incorporating Google Admob into my app.json file, I get a warning: Warning: Root-level "expo" object found. Ignoring extra key in Expo config
I am following the installation instructions of Google Admob for React Native on the following link: https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads
I am adding the android_app_id with the IDs from the Google AdMob console in my app.json file as below. After running npx expo-doctor, I get the following warning: Warning: Root-level "expo" object found. Ignoring extra key in Expo config: "react-native-google-mobile-ads"
How can I resolve this warning?
I am doubting whether this issue has effects on my app, does somebody know?
When running the app on my Android emulator, I get to see the test banner ad from Google Admob. When I install the app after packaging it to an .apk file on my physical Android phone, the app does not show any test banner ad.
I double checked that react-native-google-mobile-ads block is outside of the expo scope as instructed on the link..
Here is my app.json file:
app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "language",
    "slug": "language",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.username.project"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "886cafbd-f6cb-4888-9c87-4dfxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-9884534330xxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}

I have already consulted internet forums and chatgpt without any good results.

This is also an issue I started facing recently. It was not a problem a year ago.

It looks like previous versions of the Explo CLI encouraged users to have a top-level expo {} object in the project's app.json file.
According to this post: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/root-expo-object.md
We can instead use the root-level object in the app.json for expo configuration moving forward.
That means you can update your app.json as follows and everything should keep working as is and the warning will go away:
{
  "name": "language",
  "slug": "language",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
  "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "ios": {
    "supportsTablet": true
  },
  "android": {
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "package": "com.username.project"
  },
  "web": {
    "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
  },
  "extra": {
    "eas": {
      "projectId": "886cafbd-f6cb-4888-9c87-4dfxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-9884534330xxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}

